# POST form data as application/json

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm working on an API that receives an application/json post request, and triggers some flow.

My main issue at the moment is sending an application/json post, with data from a input form.

I've tried jQuery ajax () but since I'm expecting a page reload it doesn't seem to be working as needed.

Since this isn't part off a very complex app all I need to do is be able to take a very simple form and post it's contents into a json object and send it as the mentioned application/json request

Comment: what did you try ? or just asked a question ?

Answer (score -1):

This isn't possible.

JSON is not a supported encoding format for forms and the only other way to make a POST request is to use XMLHttpRequest.

Your best bet is to adjust the API so it supports `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded data.

Alternatively, you can make an Ajax request, store the data in a temporary data store on the server and return an identifying token and then use `location =` to redirect the browser to a URL including that token so you can render the page from it.