# how can I post JSON array as normal HTTP POST ( Form Submission )

Tags: javascript, angular, html

I am not getting a better example which show how can I post JSON array as normal HTTP POST ( Form Submission ) not ajax.

For example I want to send

```
[ 
 { "id": "1",
   "name" : "test"
 },
{ "id": "2",
   "name" : "test2"
 }
]
```

to the server as normal form submission and when the HTML response comes from server then that should be painted in browser.
I am using Angular 1.6, HTML5, JS

Comment: besides that, of course you can also post using a real `form`

Comment: example which you posted uses jquery and I dont want to use it. Can we do it without using jquery?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553039/post-form-data-as-application-json (can't close it as one until someone upvotes an answer though)