# POST request on HTML

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express

So I tried to make a URL Shrinker for fun and used the Traversy Media tutorial for it.

Here's the GitHub of his project: https://github.com/bradtraversy/url_shortener_service

In order to make it into a full Website, I have to make a UI...

But I am stuck with the POST request I am generating via ejs.

I currently have written this code in my index.ejs:

```
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <h1>Shrinker</h1>
    </header>
    <div class='main'>
        <form action="http://localhost:5000/api/url/shorten" method="POST" class="content">
             <h2 class="shortenheader">Url Shortener</h2>
             <div class="input-group">
                  <input  type="shortUrl"  class='neumorph-input' placeholder='Your Link' />
                  <input type="submit" class='neumorph-btn'>
             </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

But it always gives me the error "Invalid long url" which is coming from the code structure of the file in routes/url.js.

In the tutorial he used a simple POST request with a content-type of application/json. Which worked just fine. I am using **mongodb atlas**, so the cloud version of the database.

```
POST http://localhost:5000/api/url/shorten
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "longUrl": "https://www.stackoverflow.com"
}
```

I guess I have to use that type in my index.ejs but I don't know how to do that. Can somebody please help?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553039/post-form-data-as-application-json

Comment: "i am generating via ejs" — The POST request is generated by the interaction of a browser with an HTML form, not EJS. That the form is generated by EJS is irrelevent.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a HTML form is sent as an urlencoded string (just like the GET query string) or form-data (which can contain attachments), never JSON. See https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-enctype

To achieve that, you will have to make an AJAX request, in which you'll be able to send whatever data you want.

To form the request body you could serialize the form and then convert it to JSON. Or, the easiest way since there's only one property, you could build the body manually: `var data=JSON.stringify({longUrl:$("#shortUrl").val()});`.

Also, you have an error. `type="shortUrl"` is not valid. It should be `type="text"` and `name="shortUrl"`, or `id="shortUrl"` to be able to select it with `$("#shortUrl")`.

If you've never done it, the easiest way would be with jQuery. See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: So i have to add it to the Body with script Tags?

Something like that:
`    
<script>
        var data=JSON.stringify({longUrl:$("#shortUrl").val()});
    </script> 
 `